# TFS 2015 Publish Build Artifacts with file share met error

Tags: publish, tfs-2015

I used tfs 2015 with update3. I have created tfs build definitions as below:

[image]

Artifact Type was 'file share'.

When the build started, I got the error:

```
2017-01-22T13:05:28.4826393Z shell.js: internal error 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4836396Z 
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4836396Z     at String.charCodeAt (native) 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4846392Z     at Object.dirname (path.js:706:21) 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4846392Z     at mkdirSyncRecursive (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
14.0\Build\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:7:22) 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4856408Z     at mkdirSyncRecursive (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
14.0\Build\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3) 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4866398Z     at mkdirSyncRecursive (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
14.0\Build\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3) 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4866398Z     at mkdirSyncRecursive (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
14.0\Build\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3) 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4876401Z     at mkdirSyncRecursive (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
14.0\Build\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3) 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4876401Z     at mkdirSyncRecursive (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
14.0\Build\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3) 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4886414Z     at mkdirSyncRecursive (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
14.0\Build\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3) 2017-01-22T13:05:28.4886414Z     at mkdirSyncRecursive (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server
14.0\Build\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.28\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:16:3)
```

how to fix it?

Comment: I suspect it's caused by having too many subdirectories or a symlink (I'd guess using a lot of node packages would do that). And it's a bug in the task, which is probably best reported at the GitHub issues for the task: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues

Comment: The current version on the repo uses a different mechanism (robocopy), so I suspect this has been fixed with a newer agent version and/or TFS update. Seeing you're on TFS 207, you may need to be on 2017 to ge this fix automatically.

Comment: ok,thanks a lot,I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue: [Copy Files Task / Publish Build Artifacts Task copy to invalid UNC OR drive root produces RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/2098)  in GITHub.

Just like *jessehouwing* commented you may have to update your build agent(TFS version). Another possibility may related to permission. Please make sure build agent (which was running as a *Network Service*)  **have sufficient privileges to create folders on the network share** that it was trying to publish artifacts to.

You could also refer this similar issue: [Publish build artifacts step fails, when using Artifact Type : fileshare (TFS 2015)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eb91ab94-f359-4b47-996e-0e2fce835273/publish-build-artifacts-step-fails-when-using-artifact-type-fileshare-tfs-2015?forum=tfsbuild)